# Strongly typed way of storing type references

Tags: c#, generics

I need to store a collection of types.

All types implement the same interface `IHandler<T>`, where `T` is a parameter of the parent class.

At runtime, I enumerate the list of handlers and process a message. Each handler is created by a builder (just uses StructureMap internally). The builder exposes a method like:

```
static void DoSomething<T>(Action<T> action)
{

}
```

Of course, I only have a `Type` so can't use the above.

I've got round this by also passing the underlying interface as the generic parameter and the concrete type as a parameter:

```
DoSomething<IHandler<T>>(handlerType, h =>
                            {
                                h.Handle(message);
                            });
```

Then inside `DoSomething` I can get an instance of `handlerType` but cast it as `IHandler<T>`.

Just wondered if there was a better/cleaner way.

#### Update

In response to some of the comments.

The collection is an `ICollection<Type>`, not instances. The message handlers are created on demand, on different threads, for each batch of messages, so  creating the handlers in advance, or using `Lazy<T>`, was not an option.

Essentially I am trying to abstract away some direct references to StructureMap. Specifically, `DoSomething<T>` actually creates the handler using a nested container, before executing the action (it's `Handle` method).

#### Update 2 (solution)

I realized that I could handle (no pun intended) this better by storing a collection of `Action<T>` and creating the handlers using a factory. Here's a simple example:

```
public class SimpleProcessor<T> where T : IMessage
{
    ICollection<Action<T>> handlers;
    T message;

    public SimpleProcessor(T message)
    {
        this.handlers = new List<Action<T>>();
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void AddHandler(Action<T> handler)
    {
        handlers.Add(handler);
    }

    public void Process()
    {           
        foreach (var handler in handlers)
        {
            handler(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var testMessage = new TestMessage { Message = "Foo" };

var simpleProcessor = new SimpleProcessor<TestMessage>(testMessage);
simpleProcessor.AddHandler(m => DoSomething<TestMessageHandler>(h => h.Handle(m)));

simpleProcessor.Process();
```

I'm more or less happy with this solution.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully follow.  So the collection contains Type objects?  Or just instances of types that implement IHandler<T>?

Comment: Have you tried to use two type parameters, one for handler and second one for underlying argument type? Like DoSomething<TMessage, THandler>() where THandler: IHandler<TMessage>

Comment: You say "Of course, I only have a Type so can't use the above" - but I don't see the "of course" at all. Why do you only have a Type? When do you only have a Type? You haven't been clear about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I've updated my question to provide some more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to change `Action<T>` into `Action<dynamic>`, then you can do something like this:

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    try
    {
      var myMessage = new object();
      Action<dynamic> action = (dynamic h) => { h.Handle(myMessage); };

      Type myType = typeof(int);
      var method = typeof(Program).GetMethod("DoSomething");
      var concreteMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(myType);
      concreteMethod.Invoke(null, new [] { action });

      Console.ReadKey();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Console.Error.WriteLine(ex);
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }

  static public void DoSomething<T>(Action<dynamic> action)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("DoSomething invoked with T = " + typeof(T).FullName);
  }
}
```

Comment: It's based on my interpretation of the op's original question; he wants `DoSomething` to be strongly typed yet invoked with a `Type`, hence the required reflection.